# D3: Setting selection transform attribute in a nicer way

Tags: javascript, api, d3.js

I've been working with d3 for a while, but it bothers me that everytime I want to apply a translation to a d3 selection, I do it like this:

```
 var svg = d3
        .select("svg")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0,$1)".replace("$1", "" + (someHeight)))
```

*Note: `someHeight` is usually a calculation or else I would use string concatenation, I just think it reads better like this.*

I've been trying to find if there's a better way to set the transform, maybe through another API other than `attr`

Let me know if the question needs better explaining.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`d3.transform` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Math#wiki-transform) to parse this attribute and manipulate it in a nicer way:

```
var t = d3.select("svg").attr("transform");
t.translate[1] = someHeight;
d3.select("svg").attr("transform", t.toString);
```

You can of course also use pure Javascript to set the attribute:

```
d3.select("svg").each(function() { this.setAttribute("transform", ...); });
```

That's not nicer though. I guess calling a single four-letter function is at least about as succinct as it gets.

Comment: I upvoted because it's a better solution, less stringy, but still very verbose, the second one doesn't make much sense for me. Check an "official" example from bostock and he used the same string concat: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1345853. Thank you @LarsKotthoff

Answer (score 0):

I guess a compromise solution is just to write a simple util for each of the transform functions, for this case

```
var translateXY = function(x,y) {
  return "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")"
}
```

and then just use it whenever you need:

```
d3.attr("transform", translate(x,y))
```

Thanks for the answers.